# Temporary URL redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess, http-redirect, bluehost

I just bought a shared hosting account from bluehost.com & they gave me a temporary URL like `http://ipaddress/~username/`. The problem is that I get redirect loops when I try to access my URLs. Everything is working fine on my proper URL.

Proper URL = Accessing from the domain.

If you have any solution to this problem, please specify it will be a great help.

I have the following rewrite rules in my .htaccess files.

### redirect www to non-www version

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

### rewrite the domain.com/index.php to / (base-directory)

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

### rewrite all requests to index.php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,NE,L]

Comment: What is in your .htaccess at present?

Comment: What do you mean by "URL"s and "proper URL"?

Comment: @Pekka웃 URLs mean, any URL I try to access, it goes for a redirect loop. Eg: http://69.195.124.70/~username/~username/~username/~username/~username/~username/login-register.. And by proper URL I mean, when I try to access the website using my domain name. Eg: http://mydomain/login-register.

Comment: But why are you trying to use the IP if the proper URL works? (Not that the issue shouldn't be fixed, but...)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes its true. But this problem means that I might have done something wrong. So I am trying to fix it, because I don't know why this would happen.

Comment: @anubhava . I updated my question to shown my current .htaccess. Please check. Thank you

Comment: Try making last rules as: `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,NE,L]`

Comment: @anubhava Just checked it. It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: ok try commenting out `rewrite the domain.com/index.php` line

Comment: @anubhava Still the same problem.

Comment: @anubhava. Thanks for all the effort mate. But I thought of rewriting the http://ipaddress/~username to my domain name. I think this will avoid duplicate content issues as well.

Comment: Yes that you should do anyway as a good practice.